# Outputting Scikit-Learn Regression Residues

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

I have a mulitvariate regression model that for which I'd like to see the residuals.  I attempted to output the model's residuals via

`model.residues_`

But this has been deprecated.  Any workarounds?

Comment: Compute them?  `y - model.predict(X)`?

Comment: I deleted a duplicate answer of this one; but wanted to note also that `model.residues_` returns RSS, not residuals. If you wanted the former, you coudl use `np.linalg.norm(y - model.predict(X)) ** 2`.

Comment: @Kevin Since mine was just a comment, I think you're fine to state that as an actual answer.

Comment: There are saved in the object as `._residues` so no need to recompute it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be in StackOverflow (probably), but here's a quick workaround:

```
lm = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

np.linalg.norm(y - lm.predict(X)) ** 2  #RSS, which is what lm.residues_ returns
```